# "if" initialization statement with methods that have multiple return values

Tags: if-statement, go

I would like to have initialization statement in my `if` statement that actually uses several methods that return several values. Example:

```
func HandleArgs(args ...interface{}) {
     // Some additional checks here

     if value1, ok1, value2, ok2 := args[0].(string), args[1].(string); ok1 && ok2 {
          // Do something
     }
}
```

Go doesn't allow me to do that, responding with error:

`assignment mismatch: 4 variables but 2 values`

It is even more confusing considering that compiler can easily handle one method that return 2 values:

```
// it is OK!
if value, ok := args[0].(string); ok {
}
```

Is there any way to do what I want aside of dividing one `if` statement into two, which is ugly?

Comment: Each of type assertions on the right appears in a single value context.

Comment: @kostix, I beg your pardon, but I don't understand what does it mean

Comment: @BohdanIvanov: In Go, write this https://play.golang.org/p/xTwsA2sfJMx

Comment: @peterSO so I have to handle each "false" branch separately? Okay then. Thank you :)

Comment: I mean that a type assert in Go might be written either as `b = a.(type)` or `b, ok = a.(type)`; the latter sets `ok` to false if the assertion fails (and sets `b` to the zero value of its type), while the former panics if type asserion fails. The compiler decides which code to generate by looking at the context in which the type assert appears. In my examples, its easy for the compiler to see that the context is single-valued in the first case and two-valued in the second (and something like `b, c, ok = a.(type)` would fail to compile).

Comment: In your example, the two type assertions on the right-hand side of `:=` are delimited by a comma and hence they form _two values_ for the `:=` to assign to the respective variables on its left-hand side. This sort of forces the context for each type assertion to be single-valued. For some reason you expect the compiler to "flatten" the RHS while in fact a more logical thing to do would be attempting to write `if (w, ok1), (z, ok2) := x.(A), y.(B); ok1 && ok2 {` (which is not valid Go, either, but illustrates by point.

Comment: Okay, let's put it straight: there is no way to call more than one method in conditional initialization statement in Go, disregarding number of return values, am I right?

Comment: No, this stament is wrong. A silly example: https://play.golang.org/p/yFW_Vcwtg1J

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't use the syntax above.

You can use scoping with curly braces like so.

```
func HandleArgs(args ...interface{}) {
    // Some additional checks here

    { 
        // This will ensure all values will be captured inside the following scope
        value1, ok1 := args[0].(string)
        value2, ok2 := args[1].(string)
        if ok1 && ok2 {
            // Do something
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Yep, decided to go with this approach, seems clear enough

Comment: @BohdanIvanov Please upvote and select as correct answer